# List of Potentials from Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following list, and I am trying to create a list of potential friends which basically means everyone who is not currently friends with the person in question.

The keys of the dictionary are the persons, and the list of values are their friends.

```
person_to_friends = {'Jay Pritchett': ['Claire Dunphy', 'Gloria 
Pritchett', 'Manny Delgado'], 'Claire Dunphy': ['Jay Pritchett', 
'Mitchell Pritchett', 'Phil Dunphy'], 'Manny Delgado': ['Gloria 
Pritchett', 'Jay Pritchett', 'Luke Dunphy'], 'Mitchell Pritchett': 
['Cameron Tucker', 'Claire Dunphy', 'Luke Dunphy'], 'Alex Dunphy': 
['Luke Dunphy'], 'Cameron Tucker': ['Gloria Pritchett', 'Mitchell 
Pritchett'], 'Haley Gwendolyn Dunphy': ['Dylan D-Money', 'Gilbert D-
Cat'], 'Phil Dunphy': ['Claire Dunphy', 'Luke Dunphy'], 'Dylan D-
Money': ['Chairman D-Cat', 'Haley Gwendolyn Dunphy'], 'Gloria 
Pritchett': ['Cameron Tucker', 'Jay Pritchett', 'Manny Delgado'], 'Luke 
Dunphy': ['Alex Dunphy', 'Manny Delgado', 'Mitchell Pritchett', 'Phil 
Dunphy']}
```

Here is the code I have so far, I am not sure as to how I should update my list of potential friend.

```
def friends_score(person, person_to_friends):
    score = 0
    potential_friends = []
    for item in person_to_friends:
        if item == person:
           potential_friends = #this is where I am unsure as to how to proceed
```

FYI, the definition of a potential friend is anyone that the person is not currently friends with. For example, if Jay Pritchett was the person, the potential friends would be everyone EXCEPT for the people in the list of values: ['Claire Dunphy', 'Gloria 
    Pritchett', 'Manny Delgado']

**EXPECTED OUTCOME**

```
>>> friends_score('Jay Pritchett')

['Mitchell Pritchett', 'Phil Dunphy', 'Luke Dunphy', 'Cameron 
   Tucker', 'Alex Dunphy','Haley Gwendolyn Dunphy','Dylan D-Money', 
   'Gilbert D-Cat','Chairman D-Cat']
```

Comment: post the expected ouput for one sample.

Comment: I agree, please post what you expect as the output, since your explanation of potential friends is not clear about where those names come from.  i.e. (1) do they come from the names in the list of your `person_to_friends` example, (2) are potential friends in the `person_to_friends` example from all the names in that dictionary that are not in the person's key value pair list. (3) do potential friends come from another list

Comment: @Abby check my solution if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def friends_score(person, person_to_friends):
    # ...
    potential_friends = [
        p for p in person_to_friends if p != person and p not in person_to_friends.get(person, [])
    ]
    # ...
```

That collects all the keys of the `dict` that are not in the friends list of the specified person and are not the person themselves. That is roughly equivalent to the following:

```
def friends_score(person, person_to_friends):
    # ...
    friends = person_to_friends.get(person, [])
    # for larger data sets, you might want to convert the friends to a set
    # friends = set(friends)
    potential_friends = []
    for p in person_to_friends:
        if p != person and p not in friends:
            potential_friends.append(p)
    # ...
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution, but it assumes that all the potential friends will be listed as `keys` from the `person_to_friends` hash (dictionary).  If this is true *(I could not tell from the OP)*, then, this is a good solution.  However, if a potential friend could be listed in the `value`s list, and not be a `key`, then this should be revised.

Comment: @DavidJohnColemanII "The keys of the dictionary are the persons" -- my assumption was they are all there.

Comment: This solution will also add the person's self to the potential_friends list.  That should be removed.

Comment: thanks, nice job with the longer explanation as well.

Answer (score 0):

In case all the potential friends are the keys in the dictionary you can also use sets,

```
def friends_score(person, person_to_friends):
    s_fr = set(person_to_friends[person])
    s_fr.add(person)
    s_all = set(person_to_friends.keys())
    return list(s_all.difference(s_fr))

output = friends_score('Jay Pritchett', person_to_friends)
```

`s_fr` is the set with the person in question and their friends. `s_all` is a list of all people from keys in the dictionary. The final list is made from the difference between the two sets.

This same solution will not be able to avoid a list comprehension and list flattening with a zip in case you also need to consider people included only in dictionary values. In that case @schwobaseggl solution seems better to me.

Answer (score 0):

> You can do job in one line inside function using set :

```
return list(set([i for i in person_to_friends])-set(person_to_friends.get(person)))
```

Full code:

```
def friends_score(person, person_to_friends):
    return list(set([i for i in person_to_friends])-set(person_to_friends.get(person)))

print(friends_score('Jay Pritchett',person_to_friends))
```

output:

```
['Dylan D-Money', 'Phil Dunphy', 'Cameron Tucker', 'Luke Dunphy', 'Mitchell Pritchett', 'Alex Dunphy', 'Jay Pritchett', 'Haley Gwendolyn Dunphy']
```